# Xampp Internal Server Error after .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^UniK/(.*)$ /UniKme/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /UniKme/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I don't know much .htaccess. This is giving me an Internal Error on Xampp.

Update:
Here is the log:

Here is the error_log:

```
[Sun Feb 10 15:04:02.159903 2013] [core:error] [pid 7976:tid 1704] [client ::1:65213] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Look in the Apache error_log to see what the actual error is. Likely a rewrite loop. Add `[L]` after each of the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Here is the log:

[Sun Feb 10 15:04:02.159903 2013] [core:error] [pid 7976:tid 1704] [client ::1:65213] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: I did add [L], it is still giving me the problem

Comment: I have a similar problem like this. Would be great for a fix.